# I can't config my fails. I want always when I click button E, that it deduct fails from 10 by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, window

I have a problem. I can't config my fails. I want always when I click button E, that it deduct fails from 10 by one. Please try do solve it!

Code:

```py
fails = str(10)

def wrong():
    wrong_label = Label(wrong_frame,
                        text='wrong letter!!',
                        bg='red')
    global fails
 #   new_integer = fails - 1
    fails -= str(1)
    l1.config(text=new_integer)


window = Tk()


alpha_e = Button(window,
                 text='E',
                 bg='blue',
                 command=wrong)
alpha_e.place(y=50,x=250)


wrong_frame = Frame(window,
                    bg="red",
                    bd=2,
                    relief=SUNKEN
                    )
wrong_frame.place(x=500,y=250)

wrong_always = Label(wrong_frame,
                     text='You have only ' + fails + ' tries more!',
                     )
wrong_always.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are storing you fails variable as a string instead of an integer. You cannot do math with a string it has to be a number data type such as an `integer` or `float`. You should however convert your variable to a string in your label using `str(<your variable>)`.

**Code:**

````
fails = 10 #store the variable as an int

def wrong():
    wrong_label = Label(wrong_frame,
                        text='wrong letter!!',
                        bg='red')
    global fails

    fails -= 1 #since its an int you can now do math with it


window = Tk()


alpha_e = Button(window,
                 text='E',
                 bg='blue',
                 command=wrong)
alpha_e.place(y=50,x=250)


wrong_frame = Frame(window,
                    bg="red",
                    bd=2,
                    relief=SUNKEN
                    )
wrong_frame.place(x=500,y=250)

wrong_always = Label(wrong_frame,
                     text='You have only ' + str(fails) + ' tries more!',
                     )#convert it to a string on display with str()
wrong_always.pack()


window.mainloop()```
````

For more info on python data types go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20has%20the%20following%20data%20types%20built-in%20by,%20set%2C%20frozenset%20%202%20more%20rows%20)

Comment: Ok but how to do that? @TERMINATOR

Comment: I have added comments to help you in the code